# Laravel abort() vs return response()->json()

Tags: laravel

In Laravel, what is the difference between `abort()` and `response()->json()`?

For example:

```php
return response()->json(['message' => 'Not found'], 404);
```

and:

```php
abort(404, 'Not found');
```

---

**Edit:** I think `abort()` doesn't throw an exception if `APP_DEBUG` is `false` in `.env` file.

This is my code:

```php
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    $this->replace(array_filter($this->all()));

    if(!$this->all()) {
        abort(422, 'You must edit something.');
    }
}
```

Is there a problem if I use it to immediately stop execution and return message (before starting the validation) if all fields in the request are empty?

Comment: Still waiting for more answers? If my answer answered your question, please mark it as correct. :)

Comment: I have modified my question.

Comment: Yes it does throw an exception, it just wont show if your debug is turned off because your visitors doesn't need to see your exception traces.. You will have to add functionality/logic to your `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file in the `render()` function. Example, `if ($request->expectsJson()) {`, meaning you sent an API request with the headers `Accept: application/json`.

Comment: This is getting more bigger and broad than your initial question. If you need to educate yourself on error handling, please see: https://laravel.com/docs/errors

Comment: Thank you . add " Yes it does throw an exception, it just wont show it if your debug is turned off " to your answer and i will mark it as correct

Comment: On a related note, it is possible to provide the abort function with a custom `Response` object (in the place where you'd put the status code) if you need more control than the options provided by the `abort` function. For example, if you need a JSON response (and cannot set the accept header to `application/json`), you could do `abort(new JsonResponse('A JSON string, could also be an array etc.', 403, ['Optional' => 'Headers'])`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`response()->json(['message' => 'not found'], 404);`

Will not throw an exception and the exception handler won't handle it, it will simply return a `404` status code with your response.

---

`abort(404, 'not found');`

Will throw a `NotFoundHttpException()` exception and will be handled by the exception handler located at: `app/Exceptions/Handler.php`

---

See the function `abort()` below:

```php
public function abort($code, $message = '', array $headers = [])
{
    if ($code == 404) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException($message);
    }

    throw new HttpException($code, $message, null, $headers);
}
```

As you can see above, the `abort()` function always throws an exception. You just won't see the exception details if the `APP_DEBUG` is `false`, but it will be logged to your `logs` folder.

---

**Sources:**

- [Laravel API](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.html#method_abort)
- [App class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/c67acfdc968f487b6235435080eef62a7e2ed055/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L1115,L1133) : `\App::abort(404);`
- [App helper](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/c67acfdc968f487b6235435080eef62a7e2ed055/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L24,L46) : `abort(404);`

Comment: Did you add this code? Because I don't see it in any version of Laravel from 5 on through 8. The 'out-of-the-box' *abort* still will not show the message in any of these versions I've seen, even though the method signature indicates it's an option. They need to update either their code or their documentation. It's misleading.

Comment: @McAuley lol no, I added the source links for you, have a look ;) 
The `abort()` helper method will call `\App::abort()` if the function `abort()` doesn't exist, but if that function exists somewhere else, it will probably call that instead? So maybe try to call `\App::abort()` rather? :)

Comment: Yeah, thanks,  I was only using the one in the App helpers.php and that one won't process the message. But it looks like the *\App::abort()* will. I'll try it. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for your clarification . now i can safly use abort in transactions knowing that it's not gonna kill the process using some php native function , but it only throws an exception witch will alow the DB:transaction function to do the roleback thing whenever an abort is excecuted !

Answer (score 0):

Does not directly affect the question, but if you would like to return response from anywhere in your application (besides controller), do one of that:

**Bad approach**

```php
response()->json(['message' => 'You must edit something'], 422)->send();
die;
```

**It breaks assertion methods** `$response->assert...()`, so they don't work as expected in some cases.

---

**Better approach**

Throw a custom Exception implementing the [render method](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/errors#rendering-exceptions) where you can return your custom JSON response:

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

final class ApiNotFoundException extends NotFoundHttpException
{
    private array $responseJson = ['message' => 'Not Found'];

    public function __construct(?array $json = null, array $headers = [])
    {
        if (is_array($json)) {
            $this->responseJson = $json;
        }
        parent::__construct(headers: $headers);
    }

    public function render(): JsonResponse
    {
        return new JsonResponse(
            data: $this->responseJson,
            status: 404,
            headers: $this->getHeaders(),
        );
    }
}
```

And using it:

```php
throw new \App\Exceptions\ApiNotFoundException([
    'message' => 'Custom not found message',
    'data' => [],
]);
```